# More than 4000 chars gives string literal too long error on oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, pdo

I am currently using oci8 driver on Codeigniter.
While updating a field that will have more than 4000 chars, I was given a error :

```
 ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

So, going through few blogs, I got this:

```
    declare
    vClobVal varchar2(32767) := 'long text'
    begin
    update FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER set FKOL_LETTER_BODY=vClobVal 
    where FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID=240;
    end;
```

This worked for me when fired at Toad.
Now, I created a stored procedure and compiled as :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FMIS3.UPDATE_LETTER_BODY  ( body_text IN FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER.FKOL_LETTER_BODY%type,condition_id in FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER.FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID%type)IS
    begin    
        update FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER set FKOL_LETTER_BODY=body_text 
    end;
```

and this does not work for more than 4000 chars again. Can't I define the size of varchar2 as it gave me error. Any suggestions ?

Even tried using PDO by binding parameters, works only when the string is of size less than 4000 chars  :(

```
    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$this->db->hostname,$this->db->username,$this->db->password);
    $params = array(
        ':body_text' => "Long String"
    );
    $sth = $conn->prepare("update FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER set FKOL_LETTER_BODY = :body_text
                            where FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID=241");            
    $sth->execute($params) or die('error occured');
```

Comment: What is the difference between this question and [this other one of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948613/only-4000-chars-supported)?

Comment: @Lord Peter : data type is set as CLOB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this out :

```
declare
vClobVal varchar2(32767) := 'long text'
begin
update FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER set FKOL_LETTER_BODY=vClobVal 
where FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID=240;
end;
```

Are you sure this is not supported ?

Answer (score 5):

In PL/SQL, a `VARCHAR2` can have 32767 bytes, but in SQL only 4000 bytes. Therefore the `BEGIN` ... `END;` block worked, as it is PL/SQL, and the procedure didn't, as it is SQL.

Comment: Sorry, that was your original question, wasn't it? I'm not familiar with Codeigniter, can I point you to the OTN article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-lobs-095315.html

Answer (score 4):

`varchar2` has a limit of 4000 chars. Use [`CLOB`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/CLOB) instead.

Comment: @KusH so why are you defining your variable as `varchar2(32767)` then instead of `clob`? ideally you should define your variable as `FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER.FKOL_LETTER_BODY%type` to avoid getting it wrong.

Comment: @KusH "... ideally you should define your variable as ..." I'd go further than ideally, and say that if you're not using Type and RowType then you're definitely wrong. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: I support this answer, plus he should be using `DBMS_LOB`functionatlity to work in those clob/nclob columns in his procedures

Comment: @Najzero : Defining CLOB while creating stored procedure returning same thing. Only 4000 chars. I will search about DBMS_LOB. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidAldridge : Could not get you as well.

Comment: @KusH i mean, define your API as `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FMIS3.UPDATE_LETTER_BODY  ( body_text  IN FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER.FKOL_LETTER_BODY%type,condition_id  in FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER.FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID%type)`

Comment: @KusH then it must be a failure in the middle tier code, probably sending a varchar2 rather than clob into the API thus failing. the API definition with %type is the say to go if your table column is clob. you need to check the documentation for your middle tier code to see how to properly send in a CLOB. perhaps you should update your question to include the code you have that is invoking the API rather than the direct update that you currently have.

Comment: @DazzaL : Yeah, but how is that possible if I am able to set the value when I use PL statement.

Comment: I am using clob in my oracle DB for one of the field but still I am getting this below error while trying to insert record in it. `SQL Error: ORA-01704: string literal too long, 01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"` What should I do ?